RTK Query | Redux Toolkit | Infinite Scroll in React | Cache behavior | Previous data not resetting based on category change
I have 3 buttons for 3 categories and they are 1.See all 2.Mobiles 3.Laptop and when each category is clicked it loads the list related to that and also I am trying to implement pagination.  I am using React and Redux toolkit / RTK query.
Below is the use state and the query
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

const [category, setCategory] = useState('all');

  const {
    data ,
    isLoading,
    isFetching ,
    error
  } = useCategorySearchAPIQuery(
    {groupBy: selectedCategory, page: currentPage},
    {refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true},
  );

below is the builder query where groupBy is the selected category
  categorySearchAPI: builder.query({
      query: ({groupBy, page}) => ({
        url: `${CATEGORY_ENDPOINT}/all?group_by=${groupBy}&page=${page}`,
      }),
      transformResponse: (response, meta, arg) => {
        return response.data;
      },
      serializeQueryArgs: ({endpointName}) => {
        return endpointName;
      },
      // Always merge incoming data to the cache entry
      merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
        currentCache.push(...newItems);
      },
      // Refetch when the page arg changes
      forceRefetch({currentArg, previousArg}) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg;
      },
    }),

The needed flow is when the category button is clicked it should show only the clicked category and when scrolled it should load the next page of that category. when category is changed reset the cache with new data.
currently when the category is changed - the data is not resetting and gets mingled (category gets mixed). I need reset on category change and increment the page when scrolled.
After searching for the solution found this code setup but cant make it work as expected. What is wrong here.

To easily fix this you have to include the category param in your serializeQueryArgs:
serializeQueryArgs: ({
  endpointName,
  queryArgs,
  endpointDefinition,
}) => {
   const { groupBy } = queryArgs;
   return defaultSerializeQueryArgs({
       endpointName,
       queryArgs: { groupBy },
       endpointDefinition,
   });
},

What this will do it's to create a cache per category since category now is part of the definition of the cache key. So technically you won't reset the cache data instead you will change the cache you're pointing for. And then if a user quickly press the previos Category, the data will be there.
Suggestions:

Use either forceRefetch or refetchOnMountOrArgChange 'cause you're duplicating code.

Use Optimistic Updates updateQueryData in case you're deleting/updating objects in your cache.

Here you have a good merge func:


export function mergeData<T extends ListResponseTypes>(
  currentCacheData: BaseListResponseFor<T>,
  responseData: BaseListResponseFor<T>,
  customOrder: boolean | undefined = false
) {
  if (responseData?.pagination?.prev_page && responseData?.items?.length <= 0) {
    return currentCacheData;
  }

  if (
    isNil(responseData?.pagination?.prev_page) &&
    isNil(responseData?.pagination?.next_page)
  ) {
    return { pagination: responseData?.pagination, items: responseData?.items };
  }

  // Create a map for efficient lookups of existing entities
  const currentDataMap = new Map<number, T>();

  // Populate the map with existing entities based on their IDs
  for (const entity of currentCacheData.items) {
    currentDataMap.set(entity.id, entity);
  }

  // Iterate through each entity in the new data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set
  for (const newEntity of responseData.items) {
    currentDataMap.set(newEntity.id, newEntity);
  }

  // Create a new array to store the result
  const updatedData = customOrder
    ? [...currentDataMap.values()]
    : [...currentDataMap.values()]?.sort(
        (a, b) =>
          new Date(b.created_at).getTime() - new Date(a.created_at).getTime()
      );

  return { pagination: responseData?.pagination, items: updatedData };
}


thank you @Brogrammer I need to test this, I am new to the Reduxtookkit/RTK, as per the above categorySearchAPI code can u provide the full updated code for categorySearchAPI in JS, I tried many times but it didnt work so I followed some other way to fix this (using useState).
